# Failing to use Array.Copy() in my WPF App

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, arrays

I am a C++ developer and recently started working on WPF. Well I am using Array.Copy() in my app and looks like I am not able to completely get the desired result.

I had done in my C++ app as follows:

```
static const signed char version[40] = {
'A', 'U', 'D', 'I', 'E', 'N', 'C', 'E',   // name
 0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,   // reserved,  firmware size
 0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,   // board number
 0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,   // variant, version, serial
 0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0 ,  0     // date code, reserved
};

unsigned char sendBuf[256] = {};
int memloc = 0;
sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;
sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;

// fill in the audience header
memcpy(sendBuf+memloc, version, 8); // the first 8 bytes
memloc += 16; // the 8 copied, plus 8 reserved bytes
```

I did the similar operation in my WPF (C#) app as follows:

```
Byte[] sendBuf = new Byte[256];

char[] version = 
        {
                'A', 'U', 'D', 'I', 'E', 'N', 'C', 'E',         // name
                '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ,        // reserved,  firmware size
                '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ,        // board number
                '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' ,        // variant, version, serial
                '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'          // date code, reserved
        };

// fill in the address to write to -- 0
        sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;
        sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;

        // fill in the audience header
        Array.Copy(sendBuf + memloc, version, 8);   // the first 8 bytes
        memloc += 16;
```

But it throws me an error at `Array.Copy(sendBuf + memloc, version, 8);` as `Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'int'`.

How can achieve this???? :) please help :)

Comment: That's right. C# doesn't have crazy implicit array->pointer conversions to confuse everyone.

Comment: @chris: Then how can we achieve it buddy? :) Any alternate way?

Comment: I wouldn't be the person to ask. I'm not very experienced with C# yet, but I love the way it handles some of what I find to be C/C++'s flaws.

Comment: Can you try Object.MemberwiseClone()? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx

Comment: What do u expect `sendBuf + memloc` to do?

Comment: @chris: true..... I am also new into C# so looking forward to learn more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    sendBuf[i+memloc] = Convert.ToSByte(version[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesnt seem to work. Both `sendBuf` and `version` is empty.

Comment: Oh, are you trying to copy version into sendBuf? If so, the two should be reversed (as well as the integers). Also, it may require that the Arrays are of the same type. I'm not sure whether it will try and just cast the values or not

Comment: Typemismatch exception is thrown. Since version is char and sendbuf is byte.

Comment: You'll need to either use two of the same array type, or do the copy manually using a for loop and casting each value.

Comment: Sure thing. So, to clarify, what exactly are you trying to do? Copy the first 8 bytes of "version" to "sendBuf", starting at index "memloc"?

Comment: Yes. That's Exactly what I am trying to do :)

Comment: This works like a charm :) Thanks a bunch :) But what if I have another set of values e.g. `var myboard = new[]
            {      
                   "",
                   "S1010012",   
                   "S1010018",   
                   "S1010020"    
            };` since this is a string(var) if I have to replace it with `version` resent in Array.Copy(). how can we achieve that? :)

Comment: Are you asking how you would go about copying myboard into version? You could use the same code, you'd just have to use a different way of conversion or casting

Comment: You are absolutely right. The method is same but conversion is bothering me. How can I convert it? :)

Comment: You want to convert from a single string to a single character? In the code you posted, myboard contains strings with multiple characters. Do you want to copy all individual characters in sequentially?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18769/discussion-between-steven-wilson-and-brandon)

Comment: Dropped you a mail but its failing. Check the chat :)

Comment: This will sound bad, but I can't figure out how to get back into the chat lol

Comment: lol i can get back to chat though. Well here is the email id: `owais.blore@gmail.com` would appreciate if you drop me a mail :)

Answer (score 1):

Translated it for you. Explanations are inline.

```
var sendBuf = new byte[256];

// char in C# is a UTF-16 character (at least 2 bytes). Use byte[] here instead.
byte[] version = 
        {
                (byte)'A', (byte)'U', (byte)'D', (byte)'I', (byte)'E', (byte)'N', (byte)'C', (byte)'E',         // name
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        // reserved,  firmware size
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        // board number
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,        // variant, version, serial
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0         // date code, reserved
        };

int memloc = 0;

sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;
sendBuf[memloc++] = 0;

// C# doesn't allow pointer arithmetic with arrays. memcpy's signature is also reversed.
Array.Copy(
   version,     // Source
   0,           // Index of Source
   sendBuf,     // Destination
   memloc,      // Index of Destination
   8);          // The first 8 bytes
memloc += 16;
```

Comment: @llianPinzon: Throws an exception after Array.Copy as `Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.`

Comment: Works for me. Check how you declare your 'version' array. It should be byte[]. The same as sendBuf. Take a look at how I declared it.

Comment: @llian Pinzon: Well it works fine :) But my next step is to do the same operation with array of strings. `var myDBoards = new[]
            { 
                   "",    
                   "S1010013",
                   "S1010014",
                   "S1010015",
                   "S1010017",                   
            };` and the similar operation needs to be done with this. `memcpy(sendBuf+memloc, myDBoards [temp], 8);` where temp = 2 i.e. "S1010014" How can i achieve it? :)

Comment: Without rewriting your algo that much, you can modify your array declaration to an array of byte arrays. The solution should be similar to the one above.

Comment: @llianPinzon: You mean create byte[] myDBoards and the strings items must be implemented in the same manner as you have done with `version`.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can try. First way you can do a straight copy using System.Buffer.BlockCopy()

**e.g**

```
// fill in the audience header
Buffer.BlockCopy(version, memloc, sendBuf, 0, 8);   // the first 8 bytes
```

The other way is to just get all the bytes from the char[] using the System.Text.Encoding namespace.

```
sendBuf = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(version);
```